# animation transitions unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

hey i'm trying to make a game in unity 3D but i'm having issues with my animation transitions,

here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class animtransition : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator animate;

    void Start()
    {
        animate = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            animate.Play("RunForward");
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            animate.Play("backwards");
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W)
            ||Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S)
            ||Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space)
            ||Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D)
            ||Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A)
            ||Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.F))
        {
            animate.Play("idle");
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            animate.Play("jump");
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                animate.Play("RunJump");
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                animate.Play("RunForward");
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            animate.Play("sprint");
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            animate.Play("RunForward");
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            animate.Play("FSL");
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            animate.Play("FSR");
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            animate.Play("RunForward");
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            animate.Play("RunForward");
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            animate.Play("BSL");
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            animate.Play("BSR");
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) == false && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            animate.Play("backwards");
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) == false && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            animate.Play("backwards");
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) == false && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) == false)
            {
                animate.Play("StrafeLeft");
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) == false && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) == false)
            {
                animate.Play("StrafeRight");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the issue i'm having is with the strafing animations(BSR,BSL,FSR,FSL,Strafeleft,StrafeRight)

the animations do transition, but there is a constant transition happening between the ForwardRun/Backwards animations and the strafing animations, how do i fix this, i'm using unity 2019.4.heres a link to see what is happening with the animations in play mode

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sjBPRGeCLiGAzg7IzwkQU1wzmcEPk7Wv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: why not blend them in the animator, and use that?

Comment: i've tried that, they just constantly change when i don't want them to

Comment: then you arent telling it right...

Comment: how do i do it then?

Comment: find a tutorial .. theres no way its teachable over SO - and is also out of scope

Comment: I think you might want to use a [Blend Tree](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-BlendTree.html) .. those conditions look really weird tbh .. not even sure whether those are exclusive or if you actually trigger multiple animations for the same combination of keys ... AnimatorController already provides a visual state machine with transitions .. so you might rather want to setup those correctly and as said either use a Blend Tree right away or configure a bunch of animator parameters and setup your transition conditions accordingly

Comment: I addition to blendTree, it can be achieved using CrossFade function instead of Play.